# ASP.NET Button event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp:button event that's not firing. Its weird because I have one exactly like it in the same page that is working perfectly, but this ones event is not firing when I click the button even though it exists, the page simply reloads without any of the code in the event executing. I'd really appreciate some help. Is it maybe because its in a bootstrap collapse?

Actually, now every time I add a button this happens, the old buttons still work, but I cant add any new ones, they just stopped working.

the .aspx file:

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="GuestCarSubmit" Text="Submit As Guest" OnClick="GuestCarSubmit_Click" />
```

the .aspx.cs file

```
     protected void GuestCarSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("!!!!!!!!!!!");
        //this is not firing
    }
```

I can do GuestCarSubmit.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
that would make the events fire, but also would make the textboxes empty on postback, and I also cant find a solution to that.

---

Update:
Ok to test I set the buttons UseSubmitBehavior to false.
It turns out the button can read from another text box if submitBehavior is false but not from the one i need it to read from.
And if i set it to true it stops firing the event.
(keep in mind my other buttons don't require UseSubmitBehavior to be false to fire their events, only this one);

---

Update 2:
After Messing around with the code, it seems anything in that specific form doesn't work, how do I fix that? all of its text disappears on postback and its buttons don't fire events, but the other form the bootstrap collapse works fine.

Comment: sorry for the typo in the question

Comment: You need to share your code for us to understand what is the issue with this. With only explanation provided we can only guess the problem but can't provide the proper solution to it.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the begining of your event. It makes us known about event is fired correctly or not.

Comment: Are you saying you have multiple form tags on this one page?

Comment: @kaman bro you are my hero, thats exactly what it was :p!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
OnClientClick="return false;"
```

Like:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="GuestCarSubmit" Text="Submit As Guest" OnClick="GuestCarSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

Comment: That only makes it not fire the event even when it would

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Web Form, you need to use `RegisterStartupScript` if you want to display a sample message box at client-side.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myfunc" + UniqueID, 
     "alert('hello!');", true);
```

Comment: im not trying to display a message at client side, i know message.showbox only displays it on server side, its just an example, or a way to see if the event is working or not

Comment: Please show us ASPX page and master page (if you have one).

Answer (score 0):

Please add causes validation property into your button like below.

`Causes Validation = "false"`